# Haskell MongoDB, can't fetch _id field

Tags: mongodb, haskell, yesod

Messing about with Yesod and MongoDB. I'm using the MongoDB library directly, not using the Persistent library.

I took [this simple Yesod file server](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/advanced-haskell/building-a-file-hosting-service-in-yesod) and converted it to use MongoDB. I am trying to get the `_id` field of my documents, but instead I am getting Nothing.

My documents have 4 fields: "_id", "filename", "mime", and "content". I am able to use the `!?` operator to get any field except _id, which returns Nothing.

If `doc` is one of my documents, and I do `$(logDebug) $ show doc`, I get my document printed to the console and I can see that all 4 fields are set, including the `_id` field.

If I do `$(logDebug) $ show $ doc !? "_id"` I get `Nothing`.

If I do `$(logDebug) $ show $ head doc` I get the _id field like `_id: 12345`

`$(logDebug) $ show $ doc !? "filename"` will give me the name, like `file.txt`

I don't see anything in the docs about `_id` being treated special, so whats up with this?

Comment: Show a full, compiling example that does not behave as expected, please.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you trying to use this code in ghci. Because it's not compileable without ghci extended defaulting rules. `!?` use typeclass `Val` and show use `Show`, so `doc !? "_id"` returns `Val a => Maybe a` And `show` requires `Show a => a`.

You should declare expecting type of `!?`, for example: `$(logDebug) $ show $ ((doc !? "_id") :: Maybe ObjectId)`.